# Where can I find the heap dump?

Tags: java, vb6

I am trouble-shooting a venerable old application that is failing in a certain case in an odd place, after the end of a called method, but before the line after where the called method is called:

```
public void callingMethod() {
    try {
        log.write "Execution reaches here.";
        calledMethod();
        log.write "Execution does not reach here.";     
    } catch {
        log.write "Execution does not reach here.";     
    } finally {
        log.write "Execution does not reach here.";     
    }

    log.write "Execution does not reach here.";     
}

public calledMethodObject calledMethod() {
    doSomeStuff();
    calledMethodObject cmo = new calledMethodObject();
    log.write "Execution reaches here.";
    return cmo;
}
```

The application does not use the returned object, but I also tried putting one there in the calling method to receive the returned object from the called method as a test, but it did not help.

I have confirmed that it is not a logging issue, as I have tried various methods of logging, such as emails, and the results are consistent.

It has been suggested to me that I view the heap dump.  However, I do not know where to find this.  It is a Rube Goldbergesque application:  The shortcut calls a VB6 application, which copies a .jar from a server.  The VB application calls the Java methods through an old technology called CASCOM Bridge.  At some points, the application calls (not copies) methods from an identical jar on a different server.

Where can I find the heap dump?

I would also be interested in other methods of finding out why it is failing in such a counter-intuitive location.

Comment: What's a heap trace?

Comment: @shmosel Perhaps he said/meant "heap dump".  I have corrected the question.

Comment: I've no experience of VB6->Java but guessing just from the question title, this question might help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2409427/where-to-find-the-heap-dump-after-an-out-of-memory

Comment: @MarkJ, you would think so, judging by the title of the question, but none of the responses actually addressed his question.